# C. malloc() and free() in function doesn't work

Tags: arrays, c, malloc, free

Can someone tell me, why I can't allocate memory to the struct array through the **init()** function? When done manually in main, everything is fine. When trying it through **init()** nothing happens (Also no error message). The adress is always 0x0, I guess the null pointer.

```c
#define GAMES 100

typedef struct{
  double *scores;
}SCORES;

void init(SCORES *arr);

int main(){
  SCORES *numbers = NULL;
  init(numbers);

  printf("Adress is: %p\n", numbers);      //Still 0x0
  return 0;
}



void init(SCORES *arr){
  arr = (SCORES*) malloc(GAMES * sizeof(SCORES));
}
```

Trying it with the code below works for malloc. I get an adress but if I use **free()**, memory is still allocated.

```c
void init(SCORES **arr){
  *arr = (SCORES*) malloc(GAMES * sizeof(SCORES));
}

...

init(&numbers);

...

free(numbers);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "memory is still allocated"? How do you verify that?

Comment: C (and for this code also C++) uses pass-by-value. So `init(numbers);` is in your case the same as `init(NULL);`. In other words - the function know nothing about `numbers`

Comment: Also, obligatory comment that using `malloc()` without placement `new` is Undefined Behaviour in C++.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen When I use " printf("Size: sizeof(number[0])); " it still says that 16 bytes are allocated to that adress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first code snippet you're passing the **value** of the `numbers` variable.  In the function you change a local variable, and doing so has no effect on the variable is the calling function.

In the second snippet you correctly pass the address of `numbers` so it can be set in the function, and the call to `free` is also correct.  Just don't attempt to use the value of `numbers` after you free it, otherwise it's [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is, that when I use " printf("Size: %ld", sizeof(*numbers[0])); " I get 16 bytes. So free() does not free anything.

Comment: @jupiter That doesn't say that bytes are allocated.  The `sizeof` operator gives you the size in bytes of the type of the operand, and is evaluated at compile time.  There's no way to verify that `free` worked without using a memory debugging tool like valgrind.

Comment: This means, theoretically, that I don't need to worry when "sizeof" gives 16 bytes. Thank you.